# How do I find where I am using stackalloc in loops? (Troubleshooting CA2014 and code analyzer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Microsot.CodeAnalysis.Charp.NetAnalyzers tells me

> CA2014 Do not use stackalloc in loops

with the yellow triangle icon.

[image: Yellow triangle]

How do I find what code in my project is doing this?
There are no errors or warnings or messages when I build.

I found something in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/code-analysis/5.0/ca2014-stackalloc-in-loops) and some information on [code analysers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview)

My  projects starts like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

I am on VS 2022 17.1.5

There is some more information in the error properties
[image: more information]

Including a link to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2014)

I have searched my code for "stackalloc" but I am not using it.

Comment: Have you enabled "warnings as errors"?

Comment: Thanks. I just did but it does not help. I do have a lot more errors but none are CA2014

Comment: Strange, that analyzer tree does look completely different for me. I'm also using net6.0-windows but I don't have a group "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.NetAnalyzers", but several others. Maybe your (or my) analyzer configuration is outdated?

Comment: I added my project information in case it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just opened another of my projects which looks more like yours. When I tried to investigate, I found the possible confusion: The icon next to the rule (info, warning, error) does *not* mean that there are errors or warnings from that rule, but that the rule level is set to warning or error respectively (you can change this by right-clicking on the rule). If you where to introduce some code that would trigger that warning, you should see it in the list of the compilation errors.

Comment: Augh, that must be it but it sure is confusing!